# How to remove tabs in NopCommerce 4.40.3

Tags: nopcommerce, nopcommerce-4.0, nopcommerce-3.80, nopcommerce-4.1, nopcommerce-4.2

How to remove tabs in NopCommerce 4.40.3. I would like to remove these two Tabs below in NopCommerce. There is no CSS where I can display: none;

```
<a href="#tags" data-toggle="tab">Product tags</a>

<a href="#specification" data-toggle="tab">Products specifications</a>
```

Im using NopCommerce NoSource Code and Noble Theme

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

To modify in theme, you don't need to have the source code. Open ***Themes > NobleTheme > Views > Product > ProductTemplate.Grouped.cshtml*** (also in ***ProductTemplate.Simple.cshtml***). Replace the code from line# 105 to 134 by this given code.

```
<div class="product-details-tabs">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        @if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.FullDescription))
        {
            <li class="active"><a href="#description" data-toggle="tab">@T("products.compare.fulldescription")</a></li>
        }
        @*@if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(@Html.PartialAsync("_ProductTags", Model.ProductTags).ToString()))
        {
            <li><a href="#tags" data-toggle="tab">@T("Products.Tags")</a></li>
        }
        @if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(@Html.PartialAsync("_ProductSpecifications", Model).ToString()))
        {
            <li><a href="#specification" data-toggle="tab">@T("Products.Specs")</a></li>
        }*@
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content">
        @if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.FullDescription))
        {
            <div class="full-description tab-pane fade in active" id="description">
                @Html.Raw(Model.FullDescription)
            </div>
        }
        @*<div class="product-tags tab-pane fade" id="tags">
            @await Html.PartialAsync("_ProductTags", Model.ProductTags)
        </div>
        <div class="product-specification fade tab-pane" id="specification">
            @await Html.PartialAsync("_ProductSpecifications", Model.ProductSpecificationModel)
        </div>*@
    </div>
</div>
```

This will not render HTML code for product tag and specification tabs.